# Scrapy does not select sub-elements of the first child but of all children

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

There is this HTML:

```
<table class="myTable>
    <tbody>
        <tr>A1</tr>
        <tr>A2</tr>
    </tbody>
<table>

<table class="myTable>
    <tbody>
        <tr>A1</tr>
        <tr>A2</tr>
    </tbody>
<table>

<table class="myTable>
    <tbody>
        <tr>A1</tr>
        <tr>A2</tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

I only want to extract `A1` and `A2` one time. So I have this selection:

```
table = response.xpath('.//table[@class="myTable"]')[0]
row = table.xpath("//tr")
```

However, when checking the `len(row)` I get 6, instead of 2, even though I have checked `len(table)` and get only 1 (the first table only). How should I select then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **relative** XPath:

```
row = table.xpath(".//tr")
```

Or you can use this to work with first table on the page:

```
rows = response.xpath('(//table[@class="myTable"])[1]//tr')
```